# Load image data from bcf files in Adobe VFR dataset mentioned in deepfont paper?

Tags: python, fonts, adobe

I'm writing my implementation of deepfont(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.03196.pdf). The authors made the data(AdobeVFR data) public on which the model was trained. The images are in bcf format. How can I load image data from bcf files?

I tried visiting GitHub Issues section but was not able to get any help. I know there is a Google drive link that has raw images but they do not have train images , so want to convert the bcf to jpeg format